# Visual Studios Link.exe error: "extra operand"

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, linker

Our build process uses Visual Studios 2003 link.exe for linking.  On one machine we're seeing the following error:

```
_X86_Win32/Debug/Intermediate/OurApp.exe LINK: extra operand `/subsystem:windows' Try `LINK --help' for more information
```

It appears to be using the same version of visual studios as the other machines.  Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It looks like there's a copy of the GNU link utility somewhere in the search path. This message isn't from the Microsoft linker.

Comment: When I run `which link`, it says it's located at `/usr/bin/link`, but I am on Windows using PowerShell, so I don't know where the `/usr/bin` folder would be located.